# Getting a "Invalid hook call" on the release apk of React Native app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk, release

I am getting this error in logcat after running the signed release apk of my react native app.

```
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: See [react-native-hook-error-url] for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: This error is located at:
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in D
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in ForwardRef
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in k
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in ForwardRef
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in PanGestureHandler
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in k
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in ForwardRef
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in R
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in x
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in h
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in GestureHandlerRootView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in T
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in N
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in x
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in V
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in f
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RNCSafeAreaProvider
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in F
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in ForwardRef
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in ForwardRef
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in z
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in c
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Portal.Host
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in E
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in Unknown
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in RCTView
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in View
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative:     in C, stack:
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: sr@105:38120
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: <unknown>@817:1608
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: mi@105:60183
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: Dl@105:78547
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: unstable_runWithPriority@214:3882
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: Tl@105:71527
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: Tl@-1
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: <unknown>@105:23572
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: unstable_runWithPriority@214:3882
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: an@105:23519
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: ln@105:23454
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: ml@105:68244
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: Ir@105:43538
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: Ir@-1
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: <unknown>@448:10790
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: y@122:586
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: <unknown>@122:1889
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: y@122:586
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: o@122:1065
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: <unknown>@122:1208
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: f@138:154
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: <unknown>@138:863
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: y@143:580
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: C@143:946
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: callImmediates@143:3003
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: value@43:2918
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: <unknown>@43:1094
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: value@43:2610
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: value@43:1064
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: value@-1
12-03 11:54:48.462 30640 30680 E unknown:ReactNative: value@-1
```

complete log: http://p.ip.fi/K2d5

I never got this error when running the app in debug mode. I have checked all my hook usages, and nothing seems to be out of ordinary. I have tried fixing the versions of react, react native and react dom, and all of those should be compatible. I have also tested if my project has multiple react versions installed, and this isn't the case either.

Anyway to figure out why this is happening only in the relase apk and never in the debug variant?

Do let me know if any extra info is needed.